# Scope of nested regexes in Perl 6

Tags: raku

Is it possible to define nested `regexes` in arbitrary sequence?

The following program works as expected:

```perl6
my regex letter { <[a b]> }
my regex word { <letter> + }

my $string = 'abab';
$string ~~ &word;
put $/; # abab
```

If I swap the first two lines, compiler produces an error.

Is there a way to override this restriction (without using `grammars`)?

Answer (score 4):

You can put the regex in a variable you declare up front but later set:

```
my $letter;
my regex word { <$letter> + }
$letter = regex { <[a b]> }

my $string = 'abab';
$string ~~ &word;
put $/; # abab
```

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, `$letter` will be interpolated every time I use `word`, so in some cases this may affect performance?

Comment: believe if you bind it to a `Callable` variable, it can improve performance (and readability): `my &letter; my regex word { <&letter> + }; &letter = regex { <[a b]> };`. Using the ampersand binds it to a `Callable` which will only evaluate when we use it (lazy evaluation).

Comment: @callyalater Thanks. But if matching with `&letter` is a frequent operation, will it evaluate only once or every time the program calls it?

Comment: You can answer that question yourself by putting a `say "regex"` in the code and see if the number of times you see that on your screen matches your expectation.